# Assetic - How to disable asset combination?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I am using assetic to manage my CSS files in the Symfony 2 framework. It works well in production mode.

My problem is that in debug mode, assetic keeps combining my files into one output file. It makes it difficult to track a particular CSS style. Plus the combined file is not always updated.

How can I disable this feature in debug mode ?

**Edit**: Here is my call to assetic:

```
 {% stylesheets filter='lessphp,cssrewrite'
    '@DevoptionBaseBundle/Resources/less/front.less'
    '@DevoptionBaseBundle/Resources/less/back.less'
    '@DevoptionBaseBundle/Resources/public/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css'
    '@DevoptionBaseBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css'
    output='css/style2.css' 
    %}
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets) says `In the dev environment, each file is still served individually, so that you can debug problems more easily. However, in the prod environment (or more specifically, when the debug flag is false), this will be rendered as a single script tag, which contains the contents of all of the JavaScript files.`, so in theory there should be no problem. Can you show how your call to Assetic looks like ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a configuration for Assetic

In your config.yml, you should have

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
  debug:          %kernel.debug%
  use_controller: false
```

which means that you have to dump the assets in order tu use them.

And in your config_dev.yml, you should have

```
assetic:
  use_controller: true
```

which means that the assets are loaded each time. You should check this configuration in your config_dev.yml

Comment: I am using these settings. But when I am debugging using firebug, I still see the CSS formatting as coming from the combined file style2.css and not from the .less files.